# Android AsynkTask causes StackOverflow

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-asynctask

I'm facing a big problem. My app is loading XML files (within AsyknTask) from the net and parses them into an local SQLite Database. The problem is after approximately 22 Files and app. 1500 inserts the whole thing crashes with this error:

threadid=8: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/String;.hashCode:I
method requires 40+20+0=60 bytes, fp is 0x428cc320 (32 left)
expanding stack end (0x428cc300 to 0x428cc000)
Shrank stack (to 0x428cc300, curFrame is 0x428cc334)

Any idea?

I can parse 20 and then 20 again but not 40 at once.
The content gets cached into an ArrayList and then gets
inserted into the database at the end of each file..

I hope there is a solution or I'm scr**** :)

Cheers Ed

Comment: I believe StackOverflow predates Android. :) You're gonna have to show some code - my psychic powers are weak today.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more lines of the stack trace and the code that is parsing and doing the inserts to understand the issue. I'd guess you are doing some recursive style processing that is causing the stackoverflow.

Comment: Guys I seriously love you all!!!
Especially @cistearns! Damn mate, I would have never thought that the recursions could crash the OS. I have now just turned it over to iteration by changing 2 lines and voala... it works!

**bold**Real realy THANK YOU you saved my a**!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The level of recursions was too deep.
The OS crashed approximately within the 23 recursion with an StackOverflow.

Changed it to iteration and everything is fine now!

**THANKS!**